# Condition upon integral divergence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I have had no classes in analysis and was wondering if the following is true, and if so, how one proves it.

Proposition:

Let $f$ be a continuous function along the domain $(a,b)$. Let $f(a)$ be finite and $f(b)$ diverge. It follows that $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ diverges.

Intuitively, it makes sense that this would diverge, but the rigorous voice in my head cannot dispel the possibility of a function that contradicts me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not true. Let $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$: 
$$\int_0^1x^{-1/2} dx=2x^{1/2}\bigg|_0^1=2$$
even though at $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{-1/2}=\infty$ and $f(1)=1$.

Comment: thanks, I thought I was missing something!